# Oracle equivalent of teradata timezones

Tags: oracle, teradata

I am trying to convert the following Teradata SQL to Oracle. and the problem is that I am not able to find the equivalent time zone value in Oracle. In the below example, 'Europe Central' is not recognized in Oracle.

```
select  hi.create_date 
 , to_char( hi.create_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 

   , ((CAST(to_char( hi.create_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')||'+00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)))   at time zone  'Europe Central')
from historical_info hi
```

This below code in Oracle throws an error:

```
SELECT create_date,
   CAST(  create_date 
          AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 
    ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe Central'  
    TZ_LOSANG
FROM historical_info

ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval.
01878. 00000 - "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause: The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action: Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.
```

Can you please help me convert the Teradata time zones to Oracle recognized time zones.

Comment: What error(s) do you get? And is there a city in Europe you can use an example for that region?

Comment: am getting the following error.  ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval. 01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.

Comment: No, i do not have any particular city. Since my current data in Teradata does not have timezone classification by city, i am not able to correspond to equivalent timezone in Oracle, which has timezone values like Europe/Dublin, Europe/Jersey, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of supported time zones, [as shown in the documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#sthref387):

> You can obtain a list of time zone names and time zone abbreviations from the time zone file that is installed with your database by entering the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV 
> FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
> ORDER BY TZNAME, TZABBREV;
> ```

There isn't a simple built-in way to convert the Teradata name to an Oracle name, so you'll need to pick a suitable equivalent for each zone/region you have to deal with.

Oracle doesn't have a 'Europe/Central' time zone name, but does recognise the CET abbreviation, or any of the names which map to that abbreviation:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR';

with historical_info(create_date) as (select sysdate from dual)
SELECT create_date,
  CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'CET' TZ_AT_CET
FROM historical_info;

CREATE_DATE         TZ_AT_CET
------------------- -----------------------
2015-08-17 11:59:29 2015-08-17 12:59:29 CET
```

But that is adjusting the time from my session time zone to CET, which may not be what you want. If you are saying that the stored time represents CET then you want the `from_tz` function:

```
SELECT create_date,
  CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'CET' TZ_AT_CET,
  FROM_TZ(CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'CET') TZ_FROM_CET
FROM historical_info;

CREATE_DATE         TZ_AT_CET               TZ_FROM_CET
------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2015-08-17 12:01:40 2015-08-17 13:01:40 CET 2015-08-17 12:01:40 CET
```

From your column alias you may be trying to show that CET time in a different zone, which needs both steps:

```
SELECT create_date,
  FROM_TZ(CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'CET') TZ_FROM_CET,
  FROM_TZ(CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'CET')
    AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' TZ_LOSANG
FROM historical_info

CREATE_DATE         TZ_FROM_CET             TZ_LOSANG
------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
2015-08-17 12:02:55 2015-08-17 12:02:55 CET 2015-08-17 03:02:55 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

If you have rows with different zones and those are stored as a separate column at the moment, you can use a case expression (or decode) to specify the Oracle equivalent for each one; but you'll still have to do this mapping yourself. You could put the translation into a look-up table if this isn't a one-off task.

```
with historical_info(create_date, orig_zone) as (
  select sysdate, 'Europe Central' from dual
  union all select sysdate, 'Europe Western' from dual
  union all select sysdate, 'America Central' from dual
)
SELECT create_date,
  FROM_TZ(CAST(create_date AS TIMESTAMP),
    case orig_zone
      when 'Europe Central' then 'CET'
      when 'Europe Western' then 'WET'
      when 'America Central' then 'US/Central'
      -- when x then y for all other values you need
    end) TZ_ADJUSTED
FROM historical_info

CREATE_DATE         TZ_ADJUSTED
------------------- --------------------------------------
2015-08-17 12:16:13 2015-08-17 12:16:13 CET
2015-08-17 12:16:13 2015-08-17 12:16:13 WET
2015-08-17 12:16:13 2015-08-17 12:16:13 US/CENTRAL
```

You need to be careful to use time zones (or abbreviations) that adjust for daylight savings appropriately.